# Fast way to iteratively select indices from an array at random

Tags: python, numpy, performance

I'm looking for a fast way to iteratively select indices from an array at random if they meet some condition. The particular application here is a demographic model where I have data on the expected distribution of ages, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
popsize = int(1e6)
age_pyramid_edges = np.linspace(0,100,101) # An age pyramid with single-year age bins from 0-100
age_pyramid_data = (np.array([0.01] * 100)*popsize).astype(int) # Suppose there's 1% of the population in each age bin
```

I also have data on people's actual ages, e.g.

```
actual_ages = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=popsize)
```

Now I want to compare the expected distribution of ages to the actual distribution, and whenever the actual exceeds the expected by an amount M for an age A, I want to randomly select M indices of people who are aged A. Here's how I can do it in a loop:

```
comparable_ages = np.digitize(actual_ages, age_pyramid_edges)-1 # Digitize the ages to match the data
counts_of_actual_ages = np.bincount(comparable_ages, minlength=len(age_pyramid_edges)-1)
age_diffs = counts_of_actual_ages-age_pyramid_data

inds_to_flag = []
for age,age_diff in enumerate(age_diffs):
    if age_diff>0:
        inds_this_age = (comparable_ages==age).nonzero()[-1]
        inds = np.random.choice(inds_this_age, age_diff, replace=False).tolist()
        inds_to_flag.append(inds)
```

But this is slow, and I want to do it without looping. Is there some way to do this without a loop?

Comment: group data into a `dict(list)` where key is comparable_age and items are indexes

Comment: comparable_ages is an array so I can't use it to key a dictionary... also, I'm not sure how constructing a dictionary avoids a loop or is faster

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a fast way to choose a random element from your array, you can try something like this:

```
import random


def random_element_selector(l):
  last_idx = len(l) - 1
  random_idx = random.randint(0, last_idx)

  return l[random_idx]
```

Output:

```
>>> arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> random_element_selector(arr)
'c'
>>> random_element_selector(arr)
'a'
>>> random_element_selector(arr)
'e'
>>> random_element_selector(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I'm not sure why you need the modulo, couldn't you just do random_idx = random.randint(1, list_len) and then arr[random_idx]? But more to the point, this doesn't solve the main issue I'm having, which is how to _iteratively_ select a large number of elements based on some condition

Comment: You're right, I over complicated it. The edited version is what I intended. If you're trying to iterate through a large set of numbers, the iteration is bounded by the amount of values you are trying to access. It would probably help to use something like `reduce()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce but I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish here.